# как рандомно открывать activity в андроид?

Tags: java, android

мне необходимо открывать случайную активити после нажатия на кнопку. Но надо так же сделать так, что бы они не повторялись.У меня открывается одна и та же активити. вот мой код:

```
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          if(!validatePhoneNumber() || !validateName() || !validateDL() ){
              return;
          }

          ArrayList<Class> activityList = new ArrayList<>();
          activityList.add(Question1.class);
          activityList.add(Question2.class);
          activityList.add(Question3.class);
          activityList.add(Question4.class);
          activityList.add(Question5.class);
          activityList.add(Question6.class);
          activityList.add(Question7.class);
          activityList.add(Question8.class);
          activityList.add(Question9.class);
          activityList.add(Question10.class);




          personalInformation = "Имя: " + NameText + "\n" + "Номер телефона: " + PhoneText + "\n" + "Номер водительских прав:" + DLText;


          Random generator = new Random();
          int number = generator.nextInt(10) + 1;

          Class activity = null;

          // Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
          switch(number) {
              case 1:
                  activity = Question1.class;
                  // We are adding the number of the activity to the list
                  activityList.remove(Question1.class);
                  break;
              case 2:
                  activity = Question2.class;
                  activityList.remove(Question2.class);
                  break;
              case 3:
                  activity = Question3.class;
                  activityList.remove(Question3.class);
                  break;
              case 4:
                  activity = Question4.class;
                  activityList.remove(Question4.class);
                  break;

              case 5:
                  activity = Question5.class;
                  activityList.remove(Question5.class);
                  break;
              case 6:
                  activity = Question6.class;
                  activityList.remove(Question6.class);
                  break;
              case 7:
                  activity = Question7.class;
                  activityList.remove(Question7.class);
                  break;
              case 8:
                  activity = Question8.class;
                  activityList.remove(Question8.class);
                  break;
              case 9:
                  activity = Question9.class;
                  activityList.remove(Question9.class);
                  break;
              default:
                  activity = Question10.class;
                  activityList.remove(Question10.class);
                  break;}


          Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
          Bundle args = new Bundle();
          args.putSerializable("ACTIVITY_LIST", (Serializable)activityList);
          intent.putExtra("personalInformation", personalInformation);
          intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", args);
          //intent.putExtra(""ACTIVITY_LIST", activityList");
          intent.putExtra("NumberOfQuestion", NumberOfQuestion);
          startActivity(intent);
      }};}'
______________________________________код из другого активити_____________
'View.OnClickListener nextAnswerButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          if (YourAnswer != null){


              Intent intent = getIntent();
              Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
              ArrayList<Class> activityList = (ArrayList<Class>) args.getSerializable("ACTIVITY_LIST");

              if (activityList.size() == 0) {
                  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                          "активити кончились!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                  toast.show();
              } else {
                  Random generator = new Random();
                  int number = generator.nextInt( activityList.size()) + 1;

                  Class activity = null;


                  switch(number) {
                      case 1:

                          activity = (Class) activityList.get(0);
                          // We will now remove that activity from the list
                          activityList.remove(0);
                          break;
                      case 2:

                          activity = (Class)activityList.get(1);
                          activityList.remove(1);
                          break;
                      case 3:

                          activity = (Class) activityList.get(2);
                          activityList.remove(2);
                          break;
                      case 4:

                          activity = (Class) activityList.get(3);
                          activityList.remove(3);
                          break;
                      case 5:

                          activity = (Class) activityList.get(4);
                          activityList.remove(4);
                          break;
                      case 6:

                          activity = (Class) activityList.get(5);
                          activityList.remove(5);
                          break;
                      case 7:
                          // We will open the fourth remaining activity of the list
                          activity = (Class) activityList.get(6);
                          activityList.remove(6);
                          break;
                      case 8:
                          // We will open the fourth remaining activity of the list
                          activity = (Class) activityList.get(7);
                          activityList.remove(7);
                          break;
                      case 9:

                          activity = (Class) activityList.get(8);
                          activityList.remove(8);
                          break;
                      default:

                          activity = (Class) activityList.get(9);
                          activityList.remove(9);
                          break;'
```

Comment: если каждый вопрос имеет похожую структуру, то писать под каждый из них собственную активити несколько нерационально. Логичнее использовать одну активити, в которой только менять данные (текст вопросов). хранить эти данные можно в массиве и получать случайный, генерируя рандомное число - позицию в массиве

Answer (score 0):

Создайте список из интентов для разных Активити. Доставайте по нажатию случайный интент из списка и при каждом доставании удаляйте его.